# Що робити з "горящими путівками"?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, калька, дієприкметники

Цікавить правильна конструкція. Зрозуміло, що слово "горящий", навіть, як старослов'янізм, вживати в такому контексті невірно, але й "гарячі путівки" скидається на кальку з російської. Окрім цього натрапила в інтернеті на таке: "Невикористані гарячі путівки стають палаючими" (пропозиція однієї турфірми). Але активний дієприкметник на -ючи теж не викликає довіри. Англійський відповідник цього поняття звучить, як "Last minute tour" - тур останньої хвилини, але, можливо, є якісь інші ( кращі) варіанти, про які мені невідомо?

Answer (score 3):

Насправді в українській мові є слово *горящий*. Його наводить [Російсько-український академічний словник А.Кримського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=ukrq&dicts=1&highlight=on) як відповідник російському *горящий*:

> **Горе́ть** – горі́ти, (реже) горі́тися, пали́тися. [Без пі́дпа́лу й дро́ва не горя́ть. От як зо́лото гори́ть! Ра́на гори́ть. До горі́лки
>   душа́ гори́ть].  • Горя́щий – горя́щий [Перед хресто́м лампа́дочка
>   горя́ща (М. Вовч.)], спалені́лий [Спалені́лий со́ромом її́ вид (=
>   лицо)], розгорі́лий, (диал.) розго́рений. [Вки́нув у розго́рені
>   дро́ва]. Горе́ние – горі́ння, (без пламени) же́вріння, тлі́ння. См.
>   Пыла́ние, Блиста́ние, Сверка́ние, Мерцание.  • Находящийся в состоянии
>   горе́ния – горя́щий. [Гру́бка – ще горя́ща].

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%3F&scope=rusb&dicts=10&highlight=on) також наводить *горящий* як аналог російського *горящий*, але водночас пропонує і переклад сталого виразу *горящие путевки*:

> **Горящий** – що (який) горить, горящий, спаленілий, (разгоряченный,
>   редко) розгорілий, (диал.) розгорений:
>
> - быстро горящий – швидкого горіння, що швидко горить;
> - **горящие путёвки – гарячі путівки**;
> - горящие (пылающие) глаза – пломінкі (пломенисті, променисті, палахтючі, палахкі, палкі, полум’яні) очі;
> - горящий без пламени (тлеющий) – жаристий;
> - горящий желанием – охоплений бажанням;
> - хорошо горящий – горю́чий, горю́щий (що добре горить).

[«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17845&page=599) містить таке тлумачення прикметника гарячий:

> 4. **Надзвичайно напружений.** За гарячою роботою в полі не було часу сваритись (І. Нечуй-Левицький); А бесіда була, видно, гарячою, бо за якийсь час Сперанський кулею вилетів звідти, червоний, як рак (О. Гончар); **// Доведений до крайнього напруження; запеклий, жорстокий (про бій, стрілянину)**. На цілі кілометри плацдарм, народжуючись, клекотів гарячою пальбою, розгойданим, як море, гамором наступу (О. Гончар); В горні гарячих атак нічних Горів горніст і згоріти не міг (Л. Первомайський); **// Сповнений надзвичайного напруження (про час)**. Ревіли, гриміли гармати, Кривавий, гарячий був день (І. Франко); І так робити весь час, поєднуючи операції, економлячи хвилини гарячого часу, продумуючи кожен рух (В. Собко).

Як бачимо, точного відповідника значення немає, бо мова не про гарячий, напружений час, а про тур, який продається зі знижкою з метою швидкого продажу.

Цікаве обговорення маємо на [Форумі Словника](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t3065.html), важливим з нього є такий допис:

> Коли мова йде про усталений зворот (припустімо, що це саме так), то у
>   фразеологізмах не обов’язково кожне слово має пряме лексичне значення.
>   Оті ж гарячі жнива. Тож не такі, що доходять до кипіння? Або гарячий
>   на руку... Невже йдеться про руку, яка от-от вибухне від високої
>   температури? А заливатися гарячими слізьми? Гірко, невтішно плакати...
>   Можна навести ще чимало прикладів. Гаряча путівка - це термінова
>   путівка. Значення не виводиться зі слів "гаряча" і "путівка". Адже
>   фразеологізм відтворюється у вигляді усталеної, неподільної, цілісної
>   конструкції.

Тут же наводяться варіанти: негайні, нагальні, термінові, викидні путівки.

Comment: Жнива гарячі тому, що всі так працюють, що їм гаряче в буквальному сенсі. Гарячий на руку, тому що може погарячкувати. Заливатись гарячими сльозьми - мені не зрозуміло.

Comment: А "горящіє" путівки - це таки, що ось-ось сгорять. Гарячі ж путівки -
 це можуть бути такі, що їх багато купляють.

Comment: @Yola , але ж вони таки дійсно сгорять: день Х настане - і плакали вільні місця у тур-групі... Але я не агітую за певне слово, тим паче, що такі дієприкметники на -ущий, -ащий вважаються старослов'янизмами і вживаються дуже рідко.

Comment: Упс, мені здавалось, що ви пропонуєте варіант "гарячі путівки".

Comment: @Yola, гарячі путівки - єдиний варіант сталого словосполучення, зафіксований у словнику. І можливо, туроператори так поспішають їх продати, що їм теж щей як гаряче. Або вони їм руки пекуть - через це гарячі. Але я би обрала щось на кшталт нагальні.

Comment: Гарячі путівки - усталений вираз і тут нічого вигадувати непотрібно.